# convolutional neural network with keras give error ,UnboundLocalError: local variable 'a' referenced before assignment

Tags: python, keras, deep-learning

I write code below, but give Error below 
"UnboundLocalError: local variable 'a' referenced before assignment"
every time, I used keras.layers.BatchNormalization(), the programming give me this error. what should I do? what is wrong?

```
def make_CNN_model():

    model = Sequential()
    # input layer transformation (BatchNormalization + Dropout)
    model.add(layers.BatchNormalization(name='inputlayer',input_shape=(28,28,1)))
    model.add(layers.Dropout(name='Droupout_inputlayer',rates=0.3))

    # convolutional layer (Conv2D + MaxPooling2D + Flatten + Dropout)
    model.add(layers.Conv2D(filiters=32,activation='relu', name="Convoluationlayer_1",kernal_size=(3,3),border_mode='same'))
    model.add(layers.MaxPooling2D(name='MaxPooling_1'))
    model.add(layers.Flatten(name="Flaten_1"))
    model.add(layers.Dropout(rate=0.3))

    # fully connected layer (Dense + BatchNormalization + Activation + Dropout)
    model.add(layers.Dense(name="FullyConnectedLayer_1",units=50))
    model.add(layers.BatchNormalization())
    model.add(layers.Activation('relu'))
    model.add(layers.Dropout(rate=0.3))

    # output layer (Dense + BatchNormalization + Activation)
    model.add(layers.Dense(name = "Outputlayer", units=10))
    model.add(layers.BatchNormalization())
    model.add(layers.Activation('sigmod'))

    return model

model = make_CNN_model()
model.compile(
    optimizer='Adam',
    loss='categorical_crossentropy',
    metrics=['accuracy']
)
summary = model.fit(
    X_train, y_train_onehot,
    batch_size=5000,
    epochs=5,
    validation_split=0.2,
    verbose=1,
    callbacks=[time_summary]
)
```

Comment: please post the entire stacktrace

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wrote code below on my terminal and install again python 3 and the problem is solved .

$ conda install -c conda-forge tensorflow

Answer (score 0):

I can see some very obvious misspellings like 'rates' instead of 'rate' in `model.add(layers.Dropout(name='Droupout_inputlayer',rates=0.3))`.

Then, 'filiters' instead of 'filters' and 'kernal_size' instead of 'kernel_size' in `model.add(layers.Conv2D(filiters=32,activation='relu', name="Convoluationlayer_1",kernal_size=(3,3),border_mode='same'))`.

Finally, 'sigmod' instead of 'sigmoid' in `model.add(layers.Activation('sigmod'))`.

I don't see any variable `a` in your code, so if I were you I would make sure to fix your misspellings first, as they may be causing this problem somehow.

Comment: Thank you for this, but the error is took from first line   model.add(layers.BatchNormalization(name='inputlayer',input_shape=(28,28,1)))

Comment: don't arrive my mistake

Answer (score 0):

def make_CNN_model():

```
model = Sequential()
# input layer transformation (BatchNormalization + Dropout)
model.add(layers.BatchNormalization(name='inputlayer',input_shape=(28,28,1)))
model.add(layers.Dropout(name='Droupout_inputlayer',rate=0.3))

# convolutional layer (Conv2D + MaxPooling2D + Flatten + Dropout)
model.add(layers.Conv2D(filters=32,activation='relu', name="Convoluationlayer_1",kernel_size=(3,3),border_mode='same'))
model.add(layers.MaxPooling2D(name='MaxPooling_1'))
model.add(layers.Flatten(name="Flaten_1"))
model.add(layers.Dropout(rate=0.3))

# fully connected layer (Dense + BatchNormalization + Activation + Dropout)
model.add(layers.Dense(name="FullyConnectedLayer_1",units=50))
model.add(layers.BatchNormalization())
model.add(layers.Activation('relu'))
model.add(layers.Dropout(rate=0.3))

# output layer (Dense + BatchNormalization + Activation)
model.add(layers.Dense(name = "Outputlayer", units=10))
model.add(layers.BatchNormalization())
model.add(layers.Activation('sigmoid'))

return model
```